# Convert/display grayscale image as RGB

Tags: raster, javascript, r, leaflet, image

i want to display raster images using a color palette in a leaflet map. The images are tiled (gdal2tiles) from a single .tif to multiple .png files with values from 0 to 100.

I add the image using the `tileLayer` function.

Is there a way to use a color palette in leaflet to display the values (e.g: 0=blue, 100=green)?

if not

is there a way to transform grayscale .png (or the input .tif) to a RGBA png using a predefined color palette?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by writing the RGB values to individual layers in a stack, adding opacity information (RGBA) and write that to png.

I create a color palette with `colorRampPalette()` and get the RGB values with
`col2rgb()`

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use TileMill and MBTiles, you can do this pretty easily using CartoCSS to style the original Tiff, and output an MBTiles file.

```
#dem {
  raster-opacity:1;
  raster-scaling:lanczos;
  raster-colorizer-default-mode: linear;
  raster-colorizer-default-color: transparent;
  raster-colorizer-stops:
    stop(0,#aaf)
    stop(100, #afa);
}
```

There's an old tutorial posted [here](https://www.mapbox.com/blog/tilemill-raster-colorizer/).

As far as the original question, 'is it possible to do it *in the browser* via leaflet', no, not as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

In R, this can easily be done using the **mapview** package. For instance, displaying Landsat 8 band 5 with a customized color scheme and breaks works as follows:

```
library(mapview)

## custom color palette
cols <- colorRampPalette(c("green", "blue"))

## visualize data 
m <- mapview(poppendorf[[5]], col.regions = cols(100), 
             at = seq(5750, 30750, 500))
m
```

[image: mapview]

The 'true' **leaflet** map, if required, can be found via `m@map`:

```
> class(m@map)
[1] "leaflet"    "htmlwidget"
```

Furthermore, **mapview** allows you to add additional `mapview` (or `Raster*`, or `Spatial*`) objects via `+`, thus enabling to handle multiple tiles at once. Use e.g. `m + poppendorf[[4]]` to add band 4 to the initial map.